# Creating a dynamic URL in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, dynamic

I am making an e-commerce site with WordPress, Woocommerce, and BuddyPress. We allow members to upload images of their products. The product category name is the same as the member's username. So if exampleUser1 uploads a product image, that product is given the category 'exampleUser1'.

This is a temporary method that my team and I are using so members can see all of their products on one page (product-category page).

I want to create a dynamic URL that I can display via a button that links to the product-category page of the logged in user. I have researched how to do this using functions.php and passing variables to the URL but am having no luck getting anything to work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the category to a constant value for all users like productImage or something. Then no need for a dynamic URL, the same URL will work for all users. Just create a page template and use WP_Query in the loop like this:

```
$author = get_current_user_id();
$args = array(
    'author' => $author,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'category_name' => 'productImage',
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```